# How can the motion of the brain within the skull be stopped at the moment of impact?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure, everyday-life, collision, biology

How can the motion of the brain within the skull be stopped or controlled at the moment an object with velocity comes in contact with it. What type of a system would this require?

Comment: What’s the context? Why do you want to do this? What are your constraints?

Answer (score 1):

The brain is surrounded by incompressible liquid: when the skull is suddenly accelerated the liquid follows, making the brain follow. Note that this avoids transmitting force directly to the brain. [Problems can happen when the pressure difference in the liquid become too large, but this is usually smaller than damage from sudden rotation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3979340/).

Comment: Your link says it is usually the momentary liquid pressure that causes the damage. So while the force does not translate directly, it nevertheless translates indirectly through pressure.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is wearing a protective helmet. That helmet can be designed to reduce the size of the impact loads that the skull/liquid/brain system has to withstand during an accident which would otherwise not be survivable. That helmet can be made as thick as necessary to do its job, whereas there's almost no space available inside the skull for some sort of implant. You can wear the helmet when it's necessary and remove it when it's not, without surgical intervention.